# Matplotlib animation for an particle swarm optimazation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing a school project on evolutionary algorithms. I applied 2D particle swarm optimazation on an problem. I modified the PSO function such that I get as output:

- a vector with the best parameters
- the optimized solution
- a list of array's that contains the x-values of the particles (lijst1)
- a list of array's that contains the y-values of the particles (lijst2)

To visualise it, I wrote a loop that iterates through the list and plots the particles in 2D space. This not an elegant solution so I want to use *animate* from *matplotlib*.

I want to achieve that each frame shows an iteration of the PSO algorithm or in other words each frame should plot lijst1[i] and lijst2[i].

To give you guys an idea of the output I ran the algorithm a few iterations with few particles.

Lijst1:

```
[array([-3.        , -1.03182383, -1.29765138, -2.63259751,  1.83881941]), array([-3.        , -0.99308702, -1.61309168, -1.99811905,  1.31329269]), array([-2.26835254, -1.00436484, -1.48864562, -1.35639631, -0.49339506]), array([-1.89641446, -1.05791927, -1.22609973, -0.94357677, -1.416652  ])]
```

Lijst2:

```
[array([ 6.        ,  6.        ,  2.25620012, -0.49762621,  1.20955011]), array([ 5.39456692,  5.66213386,  1.53168852, -0.23988646,  1.97288628]), array([3.70817355, 4.68329424, 1.37540136, 0.88142455, 1.08398406]), array([2.60343502, 2.80393532, 1.67560348, 2.0280248 , 0.29435041])]
```

I used the sample code from the matplotlib website and modified it. Here is where I need help:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
%matplotlib notebook


n = 4
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(lijst1[frame])
    ydata.append(lijst2[frame])
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0,n-1,n), interval=1000, init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

What I first wanted to achieve is to plot all the frames in the same figure. The lijst1 and lijst2 have 4 indices. So I thought let the frames denote [0,1,2,3] so that each frame lijst1[i] and lijst[i] get appended to the data. In the end probably my whole figure will be filled with particles, but that is okay for now.

For some reason I don't get input at all. I'm not sure why this is. Could I please get some feedback on this?

Question: How do I modify the animation function such that I visualise the convergence process of the PSO algorithm?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the code with the understanding that your question is to loop through the contents of the list data presented to you. The change from your code is to set the range of the axes. I also removed the initialization function as I thought it was unnecessary. I added a line from the scatter plot format as a graph setting. This is just a modification to check the animation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
%matplotlib notebook
# from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

lijst1 = [np.array([-3.        , -1.03182383, -1.29765138, -2.63259751,  1.83881941]), np.array([-3.        , -0.99308702, -1.61309168, -1.99811905,  1.31329269]), np.array([-2.26835254, -1.00436484, -1.48864562, -1.35639631, -0.49339506]), np.array([-1.89641446, -1.05791927, -1.22609973, -0.94357677, -1.416652  ])] 
lijst2 = [np.array([ 6.        ,  6.        ,  2.25620012, -0.49762621,  1.20955011]), np.array([ 5.39456692,  5.66213386,  1.53168852, -0.23988646,  1.97288628]), np.array([3.70817355, 4.68329424, 1.37540136, 0.88142455, 1.08398406]), np.array([2.60343502, 2.80393532, 1.67560348, 2.0280248 , 0.29435041])]

n = 4
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-5,5), ylim=(-2, 10))
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro--', lw=2)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
#     xdata.append(lijst1[frame])
#     ydata.append(lijst2[frame])
    xdata = lijst1[frame].tolist()
    ydata = lijst2[frame].tolist()
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(lijst1), interval=1000, blit=True)# init_func=init,
plt.show()
ani.save('swarm_ani.gif', writer='pillow')
# plt.close()
# HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

[image]